# Rails Pages that don't exist resolving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, routes

I have a site that has pages like mysite.com/example.  However is someone comes in and types mysite.com/example/random_bs than the page actually resolves instead of showing an error.  How can I get the page to stop resolving and just show an error?

Rails 2.3.8

Thanks

Comment: It's at default right now.  I haven't made any edits.

Comment: map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
  map.connect "/:action", :controller => "home"

Comment: What view is being displayed for the URL `mysite.com/example/random_bs`?

Comment: mysite.com/example get's displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think 'map.connect "/:action", :controller => "home"' is your problem. Try

```
map.connect 'example', :controller => "home", :action => 'example'
```

or something like that. (Sorry my Rails 2.3 syntax is a little rusty.)